# continuity and convexity

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if $ f$ is a continuous function that satisfies $(f(a)+f(b))/2>f((a+b)/2)$ , then f is convex.

To show that f is convex, we must prove that for all $x,y$ and $q\in[0,1]$ , we have $f(qx+(1-q)y)>q(fx)+(1-q)f(y)$.  By induction, i think we might be able to show that $ \displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1;i \neq j_k}^{n-1}{2^i}*f(a)+$$ \displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1;i=j_k}^{}{2^i}*f(b)$>$f( \displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1;i \neq j_k}^{n-1}{2^i}*a+$$ \displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1;i=j_k}^{}{2^i}*b)$$*2^n$ whre $j_k$ are some numbers from the set ${1,2,...,n}$. Furthermore, showing that these sums os powers of 2 divided by $2^n$ converge to any number in $[0,1]$ , i.e. are dense in $[0,1]$, by continuity, we are done. any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Midpoint convexity:
$$f\left(\frac{1}{2}a+\frac{1}{b}b\right) \leq \frac{1}{2}f(a)+\frac{1}{2}f(b)$$
implies, by induction, that the general Jensen's inequality:
$$f(\lambda a+(1-\lambda) b)\leq \lambda f(a)+(1-\lambda)f(b)\tag{2}$$
holds for every $\lambda$ in the diadic rationals in $(0,1)$,
$$ \lambda = \frac{2m+1}{2^n},\qquad m,n\in\mathbb{N},(2m+1)<2^n.\tag{3}$$
Since the diadic rationals are a dense subset of $[0,1]$ and $f$ is continuous, midpoint convexity plus continuity imply convexity, i.e. the fact that $(2)$ holds for every $\lambda\in[0,1]$.

Comment: What if we don't assume f is continuous? Can we no longer conclude f is convex?

Comment: @H_R: there are instances of heavily irregular functions which are midpoint-convex but not convex.